# How to poll a module loaded dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loading, module-pattern

I have a module that I load in the following way in Javascript once a page is scrolled to a certain point:

```
newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.setAttribute('src','scripts/GalleryLoader-min.js');
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

This works well, but I'd like to call an init() function once loaded.
The following works but seems like something I should be able to put into it's own function and reuse:

```
var currentChance = 500;
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
    currentChance--;

    console.log("Waited");
    if (typeof NS.GalleryLoader !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("Loaded: "+NS.GalleryLoader);
        NS.GalleryLoader.init();
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    }
    else if (currentChance > 0) {
        console.log("Trying again: "+NS.GalleryLoader);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Unable to Load "+NS.GalleryLoader);
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    }   
}, 10);
```

When I attempt to put that into a function the module is always "undefined" and never ends up telling me it's loaded.  Pretty sure I'm not passing the namespace/module name currectly in order to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onload` event of the [HTMLScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement).

```
newScript.addEventListener('load', funcion() {
  NS.GalleryLoader.init();
});
```

You can even create a generic function like this:

```
function loadScript(path, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  if (callback)
    s.addEventListener('load', callback);
  s.async = true;
  s.src = path;
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);
}
```

And then use it:

```
loadScript('scripts/GalleryLoader-min.js', function() {
  NS.GalleryLoader.init();
});
```

Comment: had no idea you could use onload with scripts.  Thx for the eye opener!

Comment: @Gurnzbot if my answer was useful, please, upvote it by clicking on the arrow, and mark it as the accept answer, by clicking on the `V`. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the element [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event

```
newScript.onload=function(){
//YOUR CODE HERE
}
```